# BigInt file cannot be opened in Julia

Tags: exception, bigint, julia

I am new to julia and experimenting with it. I tried to solve a problem involving very large numbers (100^100) using julia BigInt library but when I use

```
require("BigInt")
```

at the interpreter prompt, I get the following error:

```
could not open file /Applications/JuliaStudio.app/Contents/Resources/juliaengine/BigInt.jl
```

Any ideas what is going on? I am using the latest version of 64 bit Mac OSX.

Answer (score 5):

BigInt is available by default these days so requiring them won't work. Just use them instead.